# Update Activity 1 from Activity 2's Asynk task

Tags: android

I have 2 activities, first one has a ListView that I want to update from second activitys async task.
How can accomplish this? I searched Google for a days but didn't find anything.

```
public class Activity1 extends Activity {
    ...
    //launch activity2
    }
```

In the second Activity some process is done and then i want to update Activity1:

```
public class Activity2 extends Activity {
    ...
    new UpdateDB ().execute();
    // Return to Activity 1 but UpdateDB is still working ..
    // ..after finished the work i want to update activity1
    setResult(RESULT_OK, null);
    finish();

    private class UpdateDB extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        ...
        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
            // HERE TRYING TO UPDATE activity1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What you're attempting to do is at best bad form. By definition (and documentation) an `AsyncTask` is intended for "short operations." A background task which needs to persist through `Activity` launches doesn't fit the intended design, and you ought to look at using a `Service` to handle this situation.

Comment: it is a short operation, it's a HttpResponse that last a couple o seconds.

Comment: @petey the thing is that my activity2 is finished before its asynktask is finished too

Comment: I see, I removed my [mistaken] comment from before.  seems like either you do what @codeMagic has suggested.  Or you move your UpdateDB AsyncTask and its execution to Activity 1 (or to an application class and set up an interface to handle callbacks).

Comment: @petey yaeah, i think i will have to do that, thanks guys.

Answer (score 3):

Put your code in `onPostExecute()`

```
    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
    //HERE TRYING TO UPDATE activity1
     setResult(RESULT_OK, null);
     finish();
    }
  }
```

If you need to send some data back then use an `Intent` instead of `null`. Something like

```
 protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
    //HERE TRYING TO UPDATE activity1
     Intent i = new Intent();
     // add extras to send back
     setResult(RESULT_OK, i);   // pass back your Intent
     finish();
    }
  }
```

Then in `Activity1` you have `onActivityResult()` which receives the `Intent` that you passed back in `setResult()`. I am assuming you are starting `Activity2` with `startActivityForResult()`.

Comment: yeah, i tried that but, if i put the code there, my second activity won't finish until all the process is done, what i want to try is, finish acitvity2 and after activity2's asyntask is done in the background update activy1

Comment: What "process" won't finish?

Comment: my "process" is the activity2's asynk task, it takes like 3 seconds to finish (it is in the background since i finished activity2 and now app is in activity1)

Comment: I see. You can't wait to finish `Activity2` until the `AsyncTask` is done? If not then you shouldn't be using `AsyncTask`, at least not started from an `Activity` that will be finished before the task

Comment: yeah, i was thinking on that, but i wanted to know if there was a solution for this scenario

Comment: Why would you downvote this? Unless I missed something, this makes perfect sense for what the question asked.

Comment: @Bachask8 I guess I don't understand the scenario then and why this doesn't work.

Comment: i did not downvoted you, i'm really greatful that you are trying to help me

Comment: I know, I didn't mean you. But I think I know who now.

Comment: @codeMagic, I downvoted because the question is flawed, and shouldn't have been answered without pointing the asker to a better solution. SO is intended to help folks not just now, but also in the future. If a bad question is answered (correctly or not) without identifying that there is a better solution, bad programming patterns will persist and nobody will learn anything.

Comment: @323go thank you for the explanation. However, the way the question was originally asked, this was a perfectly good solution and still could be. Yes, after a recent comment by the OP then they are going about it the wrong way. However, if they do it this way and finish the `Activity` after the task finishes then there is absolutely nothing wrong with this answer unless you can explain further

Comment: @Emmanuel, 323go: Ew, take your public displays of affection elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the changes in a [SharedPreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). So you can access it on onResume of your first activity.

If the value is changed after the onResume callback use the [`OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html) interface for being notified for changes.

Comment: i have a method to update my activity1 onResume, but the thing is that, the asynktask on activity2 hasn't finished yet, so i need to update activity1 when the asynktask is done.

Comment: Than try using the [`OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html) listener.

Comment: This could work but unless the data *needs* to be saved in `SharedPreferences` anyway, it is way more work than necessary since you already have what you need just not in the right place.

Comment: It's some kind of interprocess comunication problem. Your answer meight not work if the second activity is already finished.

Comment: Ok, I guess I'm confused on what the OP actually wants

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AsyncTask` in second Activity. Do your effort in `doInBackground` and  then call/update First Activity in `onpostexecute`